# find parameters in url using php

Tags: php, dom, query-string, domdocument

I am searching for a way to find a url that contains a parameter to extract a dynamic value

example, anywhere on my website there is a button with a link that contains characters

example.com/register/register-company.html?tx_powermail_pi1[regUid]=78

i need the id from regUid to work with queries, the 78 is not static.

thx for any help.

Comment: have you read about query strings? try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: What's your input? It's not really clear. Also, will the parameters names always be the same? Try to be more precise please.

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak I don't think he's trying to extract GET parameters following a GET request.

Comment: Do you want to grab that from other site, or it you site? In case it yours you need to use `JavaScript` instead of `php`.

Comment: use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) !

Comment: @Loamhoof, I'm sorry but I assume that he is trying to get the query strings. The question itself is not clear.

Comment: its a button on my website that contains a link with these parameters example: [link] http://example.com/register/register-company.hmtl?tx_powermail_pi1[regUid]=78 i need the id from regUid, the 78 is not static.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "http://example.com/somepage?tx_powermail_pi1[regUid]=78";
$uri = parse_url($str);
if($uri["query"]){
   #if there is query string only....
   parse_str($uri["query"], $test);
   var_dump($test);
}
```

This will work on any url. If you are trying to catch your current url get param you can just use

> $_GET['tx_powermail_pi1']['regUid']

Comment: the last part of regUid -> 78 is dynamic (not static) i can be 55, 77 or something and GET will not work because i need the id before i click on the button

Comment: I don't understand you.. the GET will get the value from the current page.. When you change your url you go to other page and there the value will be different..

Comment: as i describe its a button on my website with this link and paramater. It is not the URL from my website in the url bar.

Comment: is there a way to parse and find it via DOMdocument?