# Get a nested GET value from URL

Tags: php

Consider this, I have the following URL:

```
index.php?page=list&id=10
```

How do I GET the variable value (example, 10) from the URL to the the list.php (it uses the $_GET[id] to do stuff) rather to the index.php.

EDIT: OMG GUYS... The reason I thought it didn't work was because I had the contents on the "list.php" the same as a previous page so i was wondering why it didn't work.. Nevermind. :)

It works now.

Comment: ...or `list.php?id=10`. I don' exactly know what you mean.

Comment: Try this.... <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>

Comment: lots of answers, which you preferred?

Comment: If you are catching Current url params you use $_GET else if you have url string (not the current url) you use parse_url() then parse_str($url['query']) ... 
Please think to use search next time! 
This I wrote yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875547/find-parameters-in-url-using-php/15875683#answers-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not nested in any way. you get valus as usual, no matter at what position they are:

`$_GET['id']` (but NOT `$_GET[id]`)

in general add `var_dump($_GET);` to your `index.php` and investigate

Answer (score 2):

uhhh..

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Just include the list.php file using PHP's `include` function. That should make the variable accessible in list.php via `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your `index.php`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];  // 10
$page = $_GET['page'];  // list
```

**OR**

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];  // 10
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];  // list
```

Comment: Its good to use the correct global, using REQUEST may cause problems some times if there are POST or something else..

Comment: @Svetlio yeah, we can get both value of $_GET and $_POST via $_REQUEST

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_GET['page'];//Outputs list
echo $_GET['id'];//Outputs 10
```

Answer (score 1):

In the both pages (index and list) you may write this:

```
$id;

if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id = $_GET["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_GET variable in any php file and it should work.

I think, your url is

```
index.php?page=list&id=10
```

So, it's redirecting to index.php file. You need to include "list.php" file for correct functionality.